# Jenkins not able to allow to save the configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am running jenkins multi branch job, suddenly it not allow me to change the configuration changes, its keep on loading without any timeout issue.[image: jenkins imahe]

Can you please some one help me on this ?

Comment: Note : i am not able to save any of the configuration related like free-style project and configure system and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could have a look at the Jenkins master machine CPU and memory. Look what is consuming them. I have seen this happening when the CPU is nearly 100 %. In this case, restarting the Jenkins process or Jenkins master machine could help.
2. Try to remember/ask colleagues if there are any recent changes to Jenkins master machine. We had similar issues after installing plugins.
3. Avoid executing jobs on Jenkins master, use slave agents.
4. You may need to clean up old builds if you are not doing this already.

Comment: Hi KB, i followed all the above test case finally my jenkins back to normal mode, thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after disabling / enabling all plugins one by one, it was the "AWS SQS Build Trigger Plugin", causing the "save / apply" buttons to move, and not be functional